# Type casting, console giving wrong answer

Tags: types, casting

I am running this code on VS for Python, I am inputting a number but it's giving me the same number without exponentiating it.

````
something = (anything ** 5.0)
print(anything, "to the power of 2 is", something)```

I get this when running the console: Enter a number: 59
But it should be exponentiated by 5.0

It's the same with this example too:

```leg_a = float(input("Input first leg length: 55"))
leg_b = float(input("Input second leg length: 77"))
print("Hypotenuse length is", (leg_a**2 + leg_b**2) ** .5)```

Running the console: "Input first leg length: 55"

I appreciate any help.
````